# Access an encrypted drive from one to the other installation results in No key available with this passphrase"

Tags: mount, hard-drive, luks

Had a desktop and a laptop, both running Ubuntu 13.10. Decided to merge the two and plugged in laptop HD in tower's second slot. Both are seperately encrypted. Have no trouble booting one or the other, but for the life of me I can't access either from within the other while booted. I'm prompted for passcode (other HD shows up in mounting space in computer files, unmounted) when I select it, but either recieve a general error message (when using incorrect passcode) or this specific error using correct passcode:

```
Error unlocking /dev/sdb5: Command-line 'cryptsetup luksOpen "/dev/sdb5" "luks-793cd2e3-73b4-art7-25fe1e2b04d4" ' exited with non-zero exit status 2: No key available with this passphrase.
```

I suppose I could start from scratch, wipe the drive and add it under the tower's drive, but I'm pretty sure that isn't the only solution.

Comment: I also have a separate 255MB volume (under the 320GB encrypted that I can't access) that appears to be the first part of the second HD. THAT I can mount, but it doesn't afford me access to the encrypted bulk of the disk.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure this is the case but when you encrypt a file with gpg it creates two keys, one private and one public. I think your problem might be that you don't have in your hard disk one copy of the private key to decrypt the other hard disk.
I'm not sure about this, you may try and see what happens or wait for more experienced member to give you the solution!

Comment: Update/clarification: I can gain access to the booting portion of the disk, and I can unlock the encrypted drive with my password. Once I do, however, the mount option for the encrypted portion disappears and I'm left with only the 255 MB boot section mounted. Under disk utility, all partitions of the 320 GB drive are visible, with the encrypted portion listed as /dev/mapper/luks-793cd2e3-73b4-439b-aef7-25fe1e2b04d4, an LVM2 pv. When I try to mount from the terminal, I get an error: unknown filesystem type 'LVM2_member'. That's where I am so far.

Comment: I googled a little and found this [link](http://pissedoffadmins.com/os/mount-unknown-filesystem-type-lvm2_member.html), may be what you need!